# How to run a script only in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to run a certain script only for devices with screen size of less than 769px. Environment is WordPress.

I already have

detectWidth function to find the width of the screen.

Ideally I want to do something like:

```html
if(detectWidth() < 769)
 then execute this code:
<script>
  (function (d,s,n,id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.className = n;
    js.src = "https://example.com;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document,'script','p-mcd-sdk','mcd-sdk-jssdk'));
</script>
<pb-mcd embed-id="4f78-b5bb-b3547f1e51c8"></pb-mcd>
```

FYI this is the detectWidth function

```html
function detectWidth() {
        return window.screen.width || window.innerWidth || window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.document.documentElement.clientWidth) || window.innerWidth || window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve! update your question maybe you will get some other approach.

Comment: so just put `(function (d,s,n,id) { ...}(...));` inside `if(detectWidth() < 769) { ... }` seems kinda obvious

Comment: You can check this question I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/5503275